# Amazon EC2 UTC Time zone showing wrong

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are using Amazon EC2 instance(Mumbai Region) Ubuntu server and its time is not matching with UTC time. The server time shows 7 minutes forward than UTC time zone.

Server Time:

```
date
Fri Dec 11 05:31 UTC 2020
```

UTC Time:

```
5:24 am
Friday, 11 December 2020
Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)
```

How to match both UTC time and Server time.

Comment: did u install and is running NTP ?

Comment: No NTP is not installed.

Comment: When I run command sudo service ntp status
ntp: unrecognized service

Comment: first you need to install ntp (e.g. yum install -y ntp), then enable and start it (systemctl enable ntpd) and (systemctl start ntpd). please try

Comment: Yes now it's matching with UTC. Thank you @KenLee